# Invalid function result in Java

Tags: javascript, java

Found a js code that finds the occurrence of a substring and returns it begins substring index.

```js
    function boyerMooreHorspool( haystack, needle, start ) {
    
      var nlen = needle.length
      var hlen = haystack.length
    
      if( nlen <= 0 || hlen <= 0 )
        return -1
    
      var jump, offset = start || 0
      var scan = 0
      var last = nlen - 1
      var skip = {}
    
      for( scan = 0; scan < last; scan++ ) {
        skip[ needle[ scan ] ] = last - scan
      }
    
      while( hlen >= nlen ) {
        for( scan = last; haystack[ offset + scan ] === needle[ scan ]; scan-- ) {
          if( scan === 0 ) { return offset }
        }
        jump = skip[ haystack[ offset + last ] ]
        jump = jump != null ? jump : nlen
        hlen -= jump
        offset += jump
      }
    
      return -1
    
    }

console.log(boyerMooreHorspool("Test", "s", 0));
```

I needed to implement this in Java. I decided to rewrite, and everything seems to be correct, but the result is always `-1`?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Main
{
    public static int boyerMooreHorspool(String needle, String haystack, int start)
    {
        int nlen = needle.length();
        int hlen = haystack.length();

        if( nlen <= 0 || hlen <= 0 )
            return -1;

        int jump, offset = start;
        int last = nlen - 1;

        Map<Character, Integer> skip = new HashMap<>();

        for(int scan = 0; scan < last; scan++ ) {
            skip.put(needle.charAt(scan), last - scan);
        }

        while( hlen >= nlen )
        {
            for(int scan = last; haystack.charAt( offset + scan) == needle.charAt( scan ); scan-- ) {
                if( scan == 0 ) {
                    return offset;
                }
            }

            jump = skip.get(haystack.charAt(offset+last));
            jump = (Integer.toString(jump) != null) ? jump : nlen;
            hlen -= jump;
            offset += jump;
        }

        return -1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(boyerMooreHorspool("Test", "s", 0));
    }
}
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Why do you not use the built in function of class String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this will fix your problem, but it looks like you are switching the parameters, in the JS code it is "haystack, needle" but in your Java it is "needle, haystack". Then you are calling both functions with "haystack, needle".

Comment: This is probably the most brilliant observation I've seen all week. Welcome to SO!

Comment: This is in fact the main problem. Once that is fixed there is only the problem that the line `jump = skip.get(haystack.charAt(offset+last));` might cause a NullPointerException because the map might return null and jump is a primitive int that you cannot assign null to. One way to fix this is to use the wrapper class Integer and declare `Integer jump` instead of using the primitive type int. (And change (`Integer.toString(jump) != null)` to a simple `jump != null`)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, the argument of the method need to be rearranged, the condition of jump and the return of the method

```
    public static int boyerMooreHorspool(String haystack, String needle, int start) {
        int nlen = needle.length();
        int hlen = haystack.length();

        if (nlen <= 0 || hlen <= 0)
            return -1;

        int jump = 0, offset = start;
        int last = nlen - 1;

        Map<Character, Integer> skip = new HashMap<>();

        for (int scan = 0; scan < last; scan++) {
            skip.put(needle.charAt(scan), last - scan);
        }

        while (hlen >= nlen) {
            for (int scan = last; haystack.charAt(offset + scan) == needle.charAt(scan); scan--) {
                if (scan == 0) {
                    return offset;
                }
            }

            char ch = haystack.charAt(offset + last);
            if (skip.containsKey(ch)) {
                jump = skip.get(ch);
            }
            jump = jump > 0 ? jump : nlen;
            hlen -= jump;
            offset += jump;
        }

        return offset;
    }
```

, input

```
System.out.println(boyerMooreHorspool("Test", "s", 0));
```

, output

```
2
```